# For loop in function to move the item of the list

Tags: python

I want to move the negative numbers to the end of the list until I encounter the positive number.

**List:**

```
a=[-1,-2,2,3,4,-5]
```

**The result i want:**

```
[-2, 2, 3, 4, -5, -1]
[2, 3, 4, -5, -1, -2]
```

**My function:**

```
def f1(A):
  for i in A:
    if i>=0:
      break
    if 'Z' not in globals() or 'Z' not in locals():
     X=A
     X1=X[0]
     X.remove(X1)
     X.append(X1)
     Z=X 
    else:
      X=Z
      X1=X[0]
      X.remove(X1)
      X.append(X1)
      Z=X
    print(Z)
 
a=[-1,-2,2,3,4,-5]
print (f1 (a))
```

But the result

```
[-2, 2, 3, 4, -5, -1]
None
```

can we solve it with this function?

Comment: Find the index of the first positive number, then `lst = lst[that_index:] + lst[:that_index]`, and Bob Martin's your uncle ;)

Comment: What's all this junk about `Z` and `X`? It looks like you're severely over-complicating this.

Comment: What are you actually asking? Obviously this function doesn't produce the desired result, so it can't be used to solve the problem. Do you want to ask *how to change this function* to get the desired result? Or would you be open to a totally different algorithm, like Jack suggested? You can [edit] to clarify. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: your code is right but your function doesn't return, just prints the list, so calling a print on it will first print the list (from inside the function) and then try to print the value of the return, which is not specified hence None.

Comment: If there are only negatives, you want it to loop forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a `for` loop, but:

```
>>> def shift(lst):
...     while lst[0] < 0:
...         lst = lst[1:] + [lst[0]]
...     return lst
... 
>>> a
[-1, -2, 2, 3, 4, -5]
>>> b = shift(a)
>>> b
[2, 3, 4, -5, -1, -2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while A[0] < 0: # While the list still begins with negative values
    A.append(A.pop(0)) # Rotate left
```

This should work. For the explanation look at the comments.

---

What's more your function `f1` doesn't have a `return`ed value, so:

```
print(f1(a))
```

doesn't produce any output (only `None`, since there's no returned value)

---

Since in Python the `list`s are "passed by reference", you can do something like this:

```
while A[0] < 0:
    ...
return A # The list is already edited in global scope BUT doing this you allow the print statement above
```

Comment: Also, beside the point, but [conventionally, mutators return `None` in Python](/a/18829224/4518341). So I'd recommend either not returning `A`, or making a copy of `A` and returning that.

Comment: Yes, I knew this, but the OP wrote a print statement printing the returned value of the function, that's why I included the code.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Then I'd recommend simply removing the `print()`, and just do `f1(a)`

Comment: Please stop leaving comments along the lines of "I wrote an answer..." below the question. OP is notified already of new answers to their questions, your comments are unnecessary and simply add noise that makes work for moderators who clean them up.

Comment: is while A[0]<0 modify A safe:   Is there a defined behaviour here?

Answer (score 0):

```
def f1(a): 
    a = a.copy() 
    while True: 
        i = a[0] 
        if i < 0: 
            a.append(i) 
            a = a[1:] 
            print(a) 
        else: 
            return a
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked to move the negative numbers to the end of the list `a` until encountering the first positive number. To actually **move** them in your list, meaning to "mutate" the list in place, you could do something like this:

```
def rotateInPlaceToFirstPositive(a):
    n = len(a)
    p = 0
    while p < n and a[p] < 0:
        p += 1
    if p < n:
        b = a[:p]
        for i in range(n - p):
            a[i] = a[i + p]
        for i in range(p):
            a[n - p + i] = b[i]
```

You can use this function like this:

```
a = [-1,-2,2,3,4,-5]
rotateInPlaceToFirstPositive(a)
print(a)
# prints: [2, 3, 4, -5, -1, -2]
```

However, if you prefer to leave `a` unchanged and return a separate list that has the desired result, you can just do this:

```
def rotateToFirstPositive(a):
    n = len(a)
    p = 0
    while p < n and a[p] < 0:
        p += 1
    if p < n:
        a = a[p:] + a[:p]
    return a
```

Now, you will see this behavior when you call the function:

```
a = [-1,-2,2,3,4,-5]
print(rotateToFirstPositive(a))
# prints: [2, 3, 4, -5, -1, -2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You fell into one of python's traps.   If A is a list and you do X=A, you do not get a new list, you just get a new name.   Anything you do to list X will be done to list A and visa versa.  So when you change list X you change list A
which is the list you are looping over.   Do not modify the thing you are looping over.  To get a copy of a list use X=A.copy().  Now you can modify X without changing A.